# Laravel 5.5 connect to SQL Server using centos 7 and PHP 7

Tags: sql-server, centos7, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

Hye,
I have a new project for which need to connect laravel 5.5 with MSSQL in centos 7.
Can anyone please assist me on this step by step. As i am totally beginner on this.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel supports SQLServer out of box. You can see it from `config/database.php`

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

Now To add connection information, open `.env`, Change Database information as follows

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=your-sql-server-ip
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=your-database
DB_USERNAME=your-db-username
DB_PASSWORD=your-db-password.
```

Comment: This i already applied, but when i run php artisan migrate i see below error messages - 
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[28000]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL S erver]Login failed for user 'test'. (SQL: select * from sysobject s where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

[PDOException] SQLSTATE[28000]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL S erver]Login failed for user 'test'. 
Any Suggestions please ! @rummykhan

Comment: Are you sure, your login info is correct

Comment: Yes, My login information is correct. Also double check the way you suggested but still facing same problem. @rummykhan

Comment: Thanks.. for you suggestion i login with another details now can migrate :)

Comment: @Ism So what was the problem

Comment: it was about the db username and password, now using another username and password working fine.. thanks :)

Comment: @Ismail you're welcome

Comment: Will you accept the answer ?

Comment: Sure done :) actually my reputation is just started to increase lots of things yet can not do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plesk must use php version of instance:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php-cgi
```

for example`/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php-cgi -v` is different to `php -v`